# "Timeout waiting for task." ao tentar click em botão de webview com espresso android

Tags: android, testes, webview

Eu tenho um botão em um mdl-card de uma página html que está da seguinte maneira:

```
<div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div> <a id="btn15-minutos" href="#/" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored dialog-button">Comprar</a>
```

Possuo uma aplicação em android que acessa essa página utilizando do componente BrowserView.
Estou utilizando espresso para realizar testes automatizados neste app, e preciso que durante o teste, o botão desta página seja clicado dentro da webview, e pra isso utilizei os seguintes códigos:

```
onWebView().perform(script("return document.getElementById(\"btn15-minutos\").click()"));
```

e

```
onWebView(withId(R.id.webview)).withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "btn15-minutos")).perform(webClick());
```

Mas ambos estão apresentando o mesmo erro:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException:
>   Timeout waiting for task.

E no Android Monitor:

> I/ViewInteraction: Performing 'Evaluate Atom:
>   android.support.test.espresso.web.model.TransformingAtom@869757 in
>   window: null with element: null' action on view with id:
>   com.projeto.android:id/webview

Alguém sabe alguma solução ou já passou por isso?
Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resolvido, havia modificado a função `getUrl` do `BrowserView` e como o espresso utiliza esse método na `OnWebView`, ele não estava conseguindo encontrar/clicar no `button` da `webview`.